# How can I continue negotiating a pay raise when my boss leaves the company?

Tags: salary, negotiation

My initial boss left and we had discussed me getting a raise in a years time.

He is gone now I have to let my new boss know what was discussed.

The raise we talked about was substantial, and if I had known I would not get the raise I would not have taken the job.

How can I discuss with my new boss about the raise I was negotiating with my old boss?

Comment: Do you have anything in writing about this raise?

Comment: Also, could you clarify?  You don't think you were going to get the raise with the old boss either? What letter?  How long have you been in this job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to discuss a promised raise after the boss who promised it is gone?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40215/how-to-discuss-a-promised-raise-after-the-boss-who-promised-it-is-gone)

Comment: Before voting to close as duplicate please note that the answers to the linked question don't seem like they will answer this question. The linked question is far more specific to a situation

Comment: @RWY I agree, black and white it's the same question, but that other question is way more specific and will not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

As thursdaygeek asked in the comments, do you have anything in writing? With that your position will be substantially stronger.

Ideally your negotiations for a raise are based on your performance that is well documented, and so without any written intent from your former manager, you simply start negotiations all over again.

That being said, it sounds like you accepted the position under the assumption there would be a significant pay hike after a year? If you do not have anything in writing, nor do you have enough tenure to have good performance documented, you may be stuck. You could buckle down and build the stellar performance needed to merit a raise and negotiate next year. Since you were going to work a year at your current salary anyway, waiting another year should have minimal cost, and you can always start the hunt again if they don't meet your expectations.

My advice for the future is to only ever accept a position where you like the **current** salary offered, rather than the salary that is only verbally promised.